# javascript setters and getters

Tags: javascript, setter, getter

This has been driving me nuts! Its my first time using setters and gettings and im stumped.

```
var Person = function () {
  var address = setPersonAddress();

  this.setPersonAddress = function (a.getFullAddress()) {
    address = a.getFullAddress();
  };
};

var Address = function () {
  var address = "xyz";
  var city = "xyz";
  var state = "NY";
  var zip = "56783";


  this.fullAddress = function () {
    var name = address + ", " + city + ", " + state + ", " + zip;
    return name;
  };

  this.getFullAddress = function () {
    return fullAddress();
  };
};

var a = new Address();
```

I am trying to assign the fullAddress from Address object to the Person object address. Am i referencing getFullAddress correctly in setPersonAddress?

Comment: `this.setPersonAddress = function (a.getFullAddress()) {` < this makes no sense, you probably want `this.setPersonAddress = function (a) {` (`var address = setPersonAddress();` this too, makes no sense ;))

Comment: @Yoshi yes I agree that gives a Unexpected token error.

Comment: yeah I had a feeling that didnt make sense. Yoshi's suggestion is incorrect also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many issues with your code and you should [**lint**](http://www.jslint.com/) it to view your syntax errors.
Also, you probably want to read more about [Object Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript).

However, here's what you are trying to achieve (I think):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/FR8B8/

```
function Person(address) {
    this.setAddress(address);
}

Person.prototype = {
    setAddress: function (address) {
        this.address = address;
    },
    getAddress: function () {
        return this.address;
    }
};

function Address(fullAddress) {
    this.setFullAddress(fullAddress);
}

Address.prototype = {
    setFullAddress: function (fullAddress) {
        //naive parsing
        var addressParts = fullAddress.match(/(.+),(.+),(.+),(.+)/);

        this.fullAddress = fullAddress;
        this.address = addressParts[1];
        this.city = addressParts[2];
        this.state = addressParts[3];
        this.zip = addressParts[4];
    },

    getFullAddress: function () {
        return this.fullAddress;
    }
};

var a = new Address('15 test,Test City,Test State,J9A333'),
    p = new Person(a);

console.log(p.getAddress());
```

> I am trying to assign the fullAddress from Address object to the
>   Person object address. Am i referencing getFullAddress correctly in
>   setPersonAddress?

That could be done easily, however since you already have an `Address` value object it's probably better that the `Person` object encapsulates an instance of an `Address` object instead of a `string`.

From the example below, you can get the full address of a person by doing `p.getAddress().getFullAddress()`. Note that could create a `getFullAddress` function member on the `Person` object that encapsulate this logic to simplify things.